# puppet configuration help needed

Tags: puppet

I need your help to understand the better implementation approach for the below requirement:

1. Suppose my puppet master server name is: server.example.com which I need to update in 500 puppet agent nodes to contact to puppet master server. One way is to add server=server.example.com in puppet.conf on all the agent nodes and second way is to run the command "puppet agent --test --server server.example.com" on all agent nodes. But this needs to be performed either manually or some kind of automation needs to be performed. Is there some better way?
2. Second option is I can create a CNAME with name 'puppet' on puppet master server so that all agent nodes automatically make the communication with the puppet master. But in case I have multiple puppet master in the same domain than how I can manage it?

I will highly appreciate if someone can throw some light on the best practice to achieve this.

Thanks,
Sanjiv

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to take full advantage of puppet automation by adding `server=server.example.com` which is the address of the master. Since you are dealing with 500 nodes, manual approach is not encouraged.

By default puppet agents communicate with the master every 30minutes. But in some cases if you want to force puppet agents to communicate with master within this default time period, then use a parallel ssh or similar tool to invoke `puppet agent --test`

If you are considering multiple puppet masters then you need to ensure that DNS or the proxy server is properly configured in the network and point to right puppet master at a given point of time.

This might be helpful: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/scaling_multiple_masters.html

Comment: Thanks Avinash. Agree manual approach is not preferred. I just need to understand how we can add server=server.example.com in 500 agent's puppet.conf file. I believe we need to automate it some other way. I think puppet will not help out here because agent is not yet aware of puppet master hostname or FQDN name. 2nd way is I run "puppet agent --test --server server.example.com" on each agent node. But this also need some kind of automation. I just need to check if we can do something using puppet itself other than automating it some other way.

Comment: In general, puppet is configured during infrastructure setup. i.e with post installation scripts after loading the OS. If it is not loaded initially there should be some tool that helps to manage your cluster, i.e like parallel ssh, which does an ssh to a group of machines in parallel. You should check your environment for an existing one and push the agent configuration to desired location.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the client's puppet.conf as a template where server can take a variable in puppet or reading it from hiera. The server name will get propagated to your clients during the next puppet run by agents.

Comment: Will it really works? I mean how puppet agent identifies the puppet master name during puppet run in case of template approach as well.

Comment: @sanjiv It will work if you have all 500 nodes already puppetized and you are just updating the server name. The old and new puppetservers that you are updating should be in sync with the modules that contain client config template.      And if you don't have the 500 nodes already puppetized or if this is first time you are planning to run puppet, yes, you will need to initiate the puppet run manually with updated puppet.conf. I would use ansible to run puppet on all 500 nodes batch wise. --server argument won't ensure the server name updated in client configs for subsequent runs.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I need to check. I am running it for the first time.